# Django error: using a user-defined method inside a view model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Why do I get this error when I am trying to use `get_success_url` function inside the `LoginView` class:

`NameError: name 'get_success_url' is not defined`

**views.py**

```
class LoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    success_url = get_success_url() # url's name to redirect
    success_message = 'Welcome back %(username)s!' # A welcome message

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.get_user()
        login(self.request, user)

        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)


def get_success_url(self):
    # find your next url here
    next_url = self.request.POST.get('next', None)  # here method should be GET or POST.
    if next_url:
        return "%s" % (next_url)  # you can include some query strings as well
    else:
        return reverse('home')  # what url you wish to return
```

Comment: your tabs is wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong here.

You have defined `get_success_url` outside the class, so it is a standalone function. But you are referencing it at class level within LoginView, so it will be called at import time. However, since it's defined *after* LoginView, it won't be defined at the time it's called.

You don't want to do any of this. Firstly, put it inside the class, by using the same indentation. Secondly, **do not** call it at class level. Don't define `success_url` at all; then Django will automatically call your method to find the value.

(Also, don't use random abbreviations in your question title. What does UDF mean? "User-defined function" maybe? That is not a recognised abbreviation.)